# phonon backend plugin cannot be loaded

Tags: qt4, qt-creator, phonon

I am getting the following error when I run my music player program...

```
WARNING: bool Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend() phonon backend plugin could not be loaded 
WARNING: bool Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend() phonon backend plugin could not be loaded 
WARNING: bool Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend() phonon backend plugin could not be loaded 
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

I am using the phonon library in qt creator. If required, the OS is ubuntu 12.04.
What is the error?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your phonon plugin is missing. Are you sure you installed phonon-gstreamer or some other backend plugin?

For phonon-gstreamer, just do "apt install phonon-backend-gstreamer"